# how to install a python package from a wheel that I don't exactly know the name?

Tags: python, command-line

In a CI I create the Wheel of my package automatically and use it to run some test.

running:

```
python -m build
```

Create a dist directory with a `.whl` file.

now I would like to run the installation with test extras:

```
python -m pip install '*.whl[test]'
```

Which is of course not a legit name. I'm bad at Linux command, would it be possible to find the file name (as it's the only .whl) and use it in the string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this one needs to find the filename using a subcommand. Note that it will only work if 1 single file is generated:

```
python -m pip install "$(find dist -name *.whl)[test]"
```